# Looping over a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array

For an array within an array in JavaScript (as below),
why can't I loop through like this?

```
for (var i = 0, len= animation.length;i <len; i++) {
    for ( h = 0, len2= animation[i].length;h <len2; h++) {
            animation[i][h][0]=animation[i][h][0]*30;
            animation[i][h][1]=animation[i][h][1]*30;
    }
}
 document.write(animation);
```

EDIT)))))))))))))))))))))))))
The reason? Its because I had inadvertently made my json data which became var=animation; into a string, a string that looked like an array. THANKS FOR THE HELP, sorry for the trouble

sample 'multi-dimensional' array:

```
[
    [
        [17, 28, 1, "z"],
        [18, 55, 2, "r"],
        [11, 36, 2, "r"],
        [18, 39, 2, "r"],
        [18, 39, 2, "r"],
        [24, 36, 2, "r"],
        [18, 36, 2, "r"],
        [23, 36, 2, "r"],
        [12, 35, 2, "r"],
        [24, 34, 2, "r"],
        [18, 27, 8, "r"],
        [17, 28, 4, "r"],
        [18, 2, 6, "b"],
        [24, 15, 6, "b"],
        [18, 15, 6, "b"],
        [18, 15, 6, "b"],
        [12, 15, 6, "b"],
        [24, 21, 6, "b"],
        [17, 21, 6, "b"],
        [18, 24, 6, "b"],
        [18, 24, 6, "b"],
        [28, 31, 6, "b"],
        [8, 29, 6, "b"]
    ],
    [
        [19, 28, 1, "z"],
        [18, 56, 2, "r"],
        [11, 35, 2, "r"],
        [18, 38, 2, "r"],
        [18, 38, 2, "r"],
        [23, 35, 2, "r"],
        [19, 35, 2, "r"],
        [23, 35, 2, "r"],
        [13, 35, 2, "r"],
        [23, 35, 2, "r"],
        [19, 28, 8, "r"],
        [17, 27, 4, "r"],
        [18, 1, 6, "b"],
        [23, 16, 6, "b"],
        [18, 16, 6, "b"],
        [19, 16, 6, "b"],
        [13, 16, 6, "b"],
        [23, 22, 6, "b"],
        [17, 22, 6, "b"],
        [17, 25, 6, "b"],
        [19, 25, 6, "b"],
        [27, 32, 6, "b"],
        [9, 28, 6, "b"]
    ],
    [
        [17, 26, 1, "z"],
        [18, 56, 2, "r"],
        [11, 35, 2, "r"],
        [18, 37, 2, "r"],
        [18, 37, 2, "r"],
        [23, 35, 2, "r"],
        [20, 35, 2, "r"],
        [23, 35, 2, "r"],
        [14, 35, 2, "r"],
        [23, 35, 2, "r"],
        [19, 28, 8, "r"],
        [16, 26, 4, "r"],
        [18, 1, 6, "b"],
        [22, 17, 6, "b"],
        [17, 17, 6, "b"],
        [18, 17, 6, "b"],
        [14, 17, 6, "b"],
        [23, 23, 6, "b"],
        [18, 23, 6, "b"],
        [16, 26, 6, "b"],
        [20, 26, 6, "b"],
        [26, 33, 6, "b"],
        [10, 28, 6, "b"]
    ],
    [
        [15, 24, 1, "z"],
        [18, 56, 2, "r"],
        [11, 34, 2, "r"],
        [18, 36, 2, "r"],
        [18, 36, 2, "r"],
        [23, 34, 2, "r"],
        [21, 34, 2, "r"],
        [23, 34, 2, "r"],
        [15, 34, 2, "r"],
        [22, 34, 2, "r"],
        [18, 27, 8, "r"],
        [15, 25, 4, "r"],
        [18, 1, 6, "b"],
        [22, 18, 6, "b"],
        [16, 18, 6, "b"],
        [17, 18, 6, "b"],
        [15, 18, 6, "b"],
        [22, 24, 6, "b"],
        [18, 24, 6, "b"],
        [15, 27, 6, "b"],
        [21, 27, 6, "b"],
        [25, 34, 6, "b"],
        [11, 28, 6, "b"]
    ],
    [
        [13, 22, 1, "z"],
        [18, 56, 2, "r"],
        [11, 33, 2, "r"],
        [18, 35, 2, "r"],
        [18, 35, 2, "r"],
        [23, 33, 2, "r"],
        [22, 33, 2, "r"],
        [23, 33, 2, "r"],
        [16, 33, 2, "r"],
        [21, 33, 2, "r"],
        [17, 26, 8, "r"],
        [14, 24, 4, "r"],
        [18, 1, 6, "b"],
        [21, 19, 6, "b"],
        [17, 19, 6, "b"],
        [16, 19, 6, "b"],
        [16, 19, 6, "b"],
        [22, 25, 6, "b"],
        [19, 25, 6, "b"],
        [14, 28, 6, "b"],
        [22, 28, 6, "b"],
        [24, 35, 6, "b"],
        [12, 28, 6, "b"]
    ],
    [
        [11, 22, 1, "z"],
        [18, 56, 2, "r"],
        [10, 34, 2, "r"],
        [18, 34, 2, "r"],
        [18, 34, 2, "r"],
        [23, 34, 2, "r"],
        [23, 34, 2, "r"],
        [23, 34, 2, "r"],
        [17, 34, 2, "r"],
        [20, 32, 2, "r"],
        [16, 25, 8, "r"],
        [13, 23, 4, "r"],
        [18, 1, 6, "b"],
        [20, 20, 6, "b"],
        [18, 18, 6, "b"],
        [17, 20, 6, "b"],
        [15, 20, 6, "b"],
        [21, 26, 6, "b"],
        [18, 25, 6, "b"],
        [13, 29, 6, "b"],
        [23, 29, 6, "b"],
        [23, 34, 6, "b"],
        [13, 28, 6, "b"]
    ],
    [
        [11, 22, 1, "z"],
        [18, 56, 2, "r"],
        [9, 33, 2, "r"],
        [18, 33, 2, "r"],
        [18, 33, 2, "r"],
        [23, 33, 2, "r"],
        [23, 33, 2, "r"],
        [23, 33, 2, "r"],
        [18, 33, 2, "r"],
        [19, 31, 2, "r"],
        [15, 24, 8, "r"],
        [12, 22, 4, "r"],
        [18, 1, 6, "b"],
        [19, 21, 6, "b"],
        [17, 19, 6, "b"],
        [16, 21, 6, "b"],
        [14, 21, 6, "b"],
        [22, 27, 6, "b"],
        [18, 26, 6, "b"],
        [12, 30, 6, "b"],
        [23, 30, 6, "b"],
        [22, 33, 6, "b"],
        [14, 28, 6, "b"]
    ],
    [
        [11, 22, 1, "z"],
        [18, 56, 2, "r"],
        [8, 34, 2, "r"],
        [18, 32, 2, "r"],
        [18, 32, 2, "r"],
        [23, 34, 2, "r"],
        [23, 34, 2, "r"],
        [23, 34, 2, "r"],
        [19, 34, 2, "r"],
        [18, 30, 2, "r"],
        [14, 23, 8, "r"],
        [11, 22, 4, "r"],
        [18, 1, 6, "b"],
        [18, 22, 6, "b"],
        [18, 18, 6, "b"],
        [15, 22, 6, "b"],
        [13, 22, 6, "b"],
        [23, 28, 6, "b"],
        [18, 27, 6, "b"],
        [11, 31, 6, "b"],
        [23, 31, 6, "b"],
        [23, 34, 6, "b"],
        [15, 28, 6, "b"]
    ],
    [
        [9, 20, 1, "z"],
        [18, 56, 2, "r"],
        [9, 33, 2, "r"],
        [18, 31, 2, "r"],
        [18, 31, 2, "r"],
        [23, 33, 2, "r"],
        [23, 33, 2, "r"],
        [23, 33, 2, "r"],
        [20, 33, 2, "r"],
        [17, 29, 2, "r"],
        [13, 22, 8, "r"],
        [10, 21, 4, "r"],
        [18, 1, 6, "b"],
        [17, 23, 6, "b"],
        [19, 19, 6, "b"],
        [14, 22, 6, "b"],
        [12, 21, 6, "b"],
        [22, 29, 6, "b"],
        [18, 28, 6, "b"],
        [10, 32, 6, "b"],
        [23, 32, 6, "b"],
        [22, 33, 6, "b"],
        [16, 28, 6, "b"]
    ],
    [
        [9, 20, 1, "z"],
        [18, 56, 2, "r"],
        [8, 34, 2, "r"],
        [18, 30, 2, "r"],
        [18, 30, 2, "r"],
        [23, 34, 2, "r"],
        [23, 34, 2, "r"],
        [23, 34, 2, "r"],
        [21, 34, 2, "r"],
        [16, 28, 2, "r"],
        [12, 21, 8, "r"],
        [9, 20, 4, "r"],
        [18, 1, 6, "b"],
        [18, 24, 6, "b"],
        [18, 18, 6, "b"],
        [13, 21, 6, "b"],
        [11, 20, 6, "b"],
        [23, 30, 6, "b"],
        [18, 29, 6, "b"],
        [11, 31, 6, "b"],
        [23, 33, 6, "b"],
        [23, 34, 6, "b"],
        [17, 28, 6, "b"]
    ],
    [
        [11, 22, 1, "z"],
        [18, 56, 2, "r"],
        [9, 33, 2, "r"],
        [18, 29, 2, "r"],
        [18, 29, 2, "r"],
        [23, 33, 2, "r"],
        [23, 33, 2, "r"],
        [23, 33, 2, "r"],
        [22, 33, 2, "r"],
        [15, 27, 2, "r"],
        [11, 20, 8, "r"],
        [8, 20, 4, "r"],
        [18, 1, 6, "b"],
        [18, 25, 6, "b"],
        [19, 18, 6, "b"],
        [12, 20, 6, "b"],
        [11, 20, 6, "b"],
        [23, 31, 6, "b"],
        [17, 28, 6, "b"],
        [10, 32, 6, "b"],
        [23, 33, 6, "b"],
        [22, 33, 6, "b"],
        [18, 28, 6, "b"]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Inner loop needs `animation[i].length`

Comment: Just the good ol' http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: thanks for the editing prowess!

Comment: are you getting any error messages? with your latest edits it is supposed to work just fine. are you sure `animation` has the expected value?

Comment: @basilkum, it outputs as it was pre loop, i can't see any errors, FIREFOX is turning and turning still, not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same length variable for both loops. It's not guaranteed that the nested arrays have the same length as the outer array. It should look more like this:

```
for (var i = 0, len= animation.length;i <len; i++) {
    for ( h = 0, len2= animation[i].length;h <len2; h++) {
            animation[i][h][0]=animation[i][h][0]*30;
            animation[i][h][1]=animation[i][h][1]*30;
    }
}
```

Comment: whilst true, it doesn-t solve the problem (before trying to improve the code i was using h<$animation[1].length; but stll no dice

Comment: sorry, what part of the problem did this not solve? if it's related to the inner part of the loop, i don't know what that's supposed to do, as it's not explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

When posting code, please only post a minimal example that demonstrates the issue. Also, post complete code that can be copied, pasted and run without modification otherwise your issue may be lost in the missing part of the post.

The following shows that your code as posted, works. But there is nothing to link it to the (excessive amount of) data that you posted.

```
var animation = 
[
    [
        [17, 28, 1, "z"],
        [28, 31, 6, "b"],
        [8, 29, 6, "b"]
    ],
    [
        [19, 28, 1, "z"],
        [17, 25, 6, "b"],
        [19, 25, 6, "b"],
        [27, 32, 6, "b"],
        [9, 28, 6, "b"]
    ]
]

for (var i = 0, len= animation.length;i <len; i++) {
    for ( h = 0, len2= animation[i].length;h <len2; h++) {
            animation[i][h][0]=animation[i][h][0]*30;
            animation[i][h][1]=animation[i][h][1]*30;
    }
}

document.write(animation);
```

Comment: Sorry, will get down off my soap box…

Comment: ha ha I wasn't being sarcastic! I had been lazy due to frustration and if everyone did the same SO would be full of blinding data and little visible information. Presentation is a vital aspect to good programming, no?